# code executed in wrong order in Firefox with setTimeout after alert

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout, alert

Run the following code in any browser( try it several times):

```
console.log('processing: task #1');
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log('processing: task #3');
},0);
alert('See console logs');
console.log('processing: task #2');
```

In my understanding, the above code would result console output being:

```
"processing: task #1"
"processing: task #2"
"processing: task #3"
```

But in Firefox( v38.0.1), it produces the following output:

```
"processing: task #1"
"processing: task #3"
"processing: task #2"
```

Please explain why Firefox do it this way. Don't know if it's a bug or Firefox's own standard.

You can see a live demo here: http://jsbin.com/cijonu

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Firefox 38 / linux.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Firefox 38.0.1 / Windows 8 64-bit

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Firefox 38.0.1 on Linux either.

Comment: Firefox has already been inserting resize events inide alerts, but... timeouts? I guess the answer is then, don't use alerts to ensure synchronous execution.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Firefox 37.0.2 on Windows 7

Comment: Actually, I can reproduce. But you have to run it multiple times in a row.

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce it too when running it 4~5 times, just like @FlorianMargaine

Comment: The problem is almost certainly the `alert`. You should never have alerts in your code, it's a wicked thing.

Comment: This must be a bug... alerts should prevent the event loop from running

Comment: @JanDvorak the `setTimeout` is fired before the `alert`, and `alert` may defer all code after it.

Comment: @Hacketo it should. But this question says firefox lets timeouts events happen while the alert is being shown

Comment: @JanDvorak I don't see that in the post, only talking about the order of `console.log`

Comment: @Hacketo yes. that order shows that either timeouts are being executed synchronously (severe bug) or while an alert is being shown (still very a bad bug, but less unexpected)

Comment: @JanDvorak I guess I would expect this behavior, since the function in `setTimeout` will be fired on the next stack of execution, and alert may block execution and defer the next lines of code ( so appending these lines on the next stack of execution again). (I never use alert)

Comment: @Hacketo alerts prevent synchronous execution but they should also pause the event loop. Not sure if there's a spec saying that somewhere, but it definitely is the expected behavior

Comment: @DenysSéguret sorry I didn't notice there's one pre-condition: you need to open more than one tab in Firefox before running the code. I will update the question.

Comment: Yes, [`alert` is required, if it pauses the synchronous execution (which it technically doesn't have to do), to pause the event loop as well.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#dom-alert)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug. The HTML5 specification doesn't allow event handlers to fire while an alert is being shown:

[Section 6.1.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-loop) defines the event loop.

<sup>In 6.1.4.2 this section also helps provide some guarantees about the order in which events are fired (point 1 of the event loop algorithm) and that the document gets rendered after an event handler returns (point 4.3)</sup>

[Section 6.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timer-initialization-steps) defines the timer initialisation steps for `setTimeout`:

> ...
>   14. [Queue](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) the task `task`.

<sub>point 12 of this section also provides a guarantee about the relative ordering of multiple timeouts - a timeout issued later may not fire before a timeout issued earlier unless it has a shorter timeout</sub>

[Section 6.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#dom-alert) defines the `alert` behavior.

> 3. Optionally, abort these steps. (For example, the user agent might give the user the option to ignore all alerts, and would thus abort at this step whenever the method was invoked.)
> 4. Show the given `message` to the user.
> 5. Optionally, [pause](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#pause) while waiting for the user to acknowledge the message.

(note: pausing is mandatory for `confirm` and `prompt` as they return based on the user actions)

The specification of pausing says:

> Some of the algorithms in this specification, for historical reasons, require the user agent to pause while running a task until a condition goal is met. This means running the following steps:
>   ...
>   3. **Wait until the condition `goal` is met. While a user agent has a paused task, the corresponding event loop must not run further tasks, and any script in the currently running task must block.** User agents should remain responsive to user input while paused, however, albeit in a reduced capacity since the event loop will not be doing anything.

(emphasis mine)

Note that if `alert` does not pause, the console logs must still be in order: First synchronous execution completes (log #2), then the timeout fires (log #3), then the user closes the alert. As observed by the page javascript, the behavior is the same as if the user has closed the alert box immediately.

Comment: well explained why this is a bug.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Firefox bug.

I've reported it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1169568

Comment: I've reported a bug on Bugzilla here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1167575 . But it seems no one is touching this issue, so I'm wondering if it's actually a bug.

Comment: I will accept your answer when your bug report is confirmed valid.

Comment: @Greg it is a bug. The spec requires `alert` to either 1) not pause synchronous execution  or 2) pause the event loop as well.

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, I did that after seeing OP also reported the bug.